# Python Socket Receive for multiple TCP headers

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am a beginner with Python, so please consider I will not be able to give complete information in one go.

My requirements are:

I am implementing a Python based socket receiver. Implementation is complete but I have to handle a message/data stream with following:

1) Data stream will have 4 different types of message in it. Each having a message header (1-4) which I am getting using

```
type_msg=struct.unpack('B',data[0])[0]
```

2) Second part is that next 4 bits will have the actual length of the data of each type according to the header. So,

```
actual_len = struct.unpack('i', data[1:5])[0]
```

3) Next part is to handle the data received and play with it. Length of received data can be taken by ** rcv_len = len(data)**

I am facing problem in situation where I receive less/more data then than actual length. I have the **delta-length which I have got using actual_len-rcv_len**

I am unable to handle code after this. What is the best way to receive delta message and then appending it to received data till now. I also want to write the data into a file.

I have read about data.append but not very sure about how to implement it. Should I again receive data using **conn.recv(del_len)** or do something else.

Any guidance will be very helpful.

Adding Code below:

```
BUFFER_SIZE=40960
import socket
import struct

class mySocket:

def __init__(self, sock=None):
    if sock is None:
        self.sock = socket.socket(
                        socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind(('', 9988)) 
        self.sock.listen(1)
    else:
        self.sock = sock

def receive_data(self):
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    conn, client_address= self.sock.accept()
    print "Connected to client with IP---->", client_address
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) 
        if not data:
            print "Connection is Broken.."
            break
        else: 
            if data<5:
                print "MSG HEADER STILL NOT COMPLETELY RECEIVED"
            else:
                type_msg=struct.unpack('B',data[0])
                msg_type = type_msg[0]
                rcv_len = len(data)
                actual_len = struct.unpack('i', data[1:5])[0]
                print "Received Length: ",rcv_len
                print "Actual Length : ",actual_len
                if msg_type == 1:
                    f_cfg = open("test.xml", "wb")
                    if rcv_len < actual_len:
                        del_len = actual_len-rcv_len
                        print "Delta length :",del_len
                        while (del_len):
                            print "Receiving Falcon Config File..."
                            print "Actual Length : ",actual_len,"and total length now is",rcv_len+del_len
                            f_cfg.write(data[5:rcv_len]+data[del_len]) //Feel something wrong in this.
                    else:
                        print "Writing Falcon config"
                        f_cfg.write(data[5:])
                    f_cfg.close()
                else:
                    print "INVALID MESSAGE TYPE. DATA CORRUPTED !!"
                    break

    conn.send("Data Received")
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. The tricks are to never read in more data than you need at any step so you don't have to worry about over shooting. And just keep track of the data remaining by subtracting the amount you receive each time so you don't have to juggle multiple variables.

Here is a helper that will read in a fixed size buffer. Use it to read in the header.

```
def recv_exactly(sock, count):
    """receive exactly count bytes from socket. If socket is closed,
    empty string is returned even if some data received.
    """
    buf = []
    while count:
        data = sock.recv(count)
        if not data:
            return ''
        count -= len(data)
        buf.append(data)
    return ''.join(buf)
```

You could use the same function to read in the data, but its better to write the file as you go. Notice when receiving data, the `min` function is used to decide on a recv size.

```
def receive_data(self):
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    conn, client_address= self.sock.accept()
    print "Connected to client with IP---->", client_address
    while True:
        # read fix length header
        data = recv_exactly(conn, 5) 
        if not data:
            print "Connection is Broken.."
            break
        msg_type, data_len = struct.unpack('Bi', data)

        if msg_type == 1:
            # read stream into file
            with open('test.xml', 'wb') as fp:
                while data_len:
                    # read next chunk. on the last chunk, limit recv to the
                    # known amount of outstanding data
                    data = conn.recv(min(data_len, BUFFER_SIZE))
                    if not data:
                        print "ERROR: TOO FEW BYTES RECEIVED"
                        break
                    fp.write(data)
                    data_len -= len(data)

    conn.send("Data Received")
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer... I will try and get back on this.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to handle the receive part when I have to check for 2 different msg_type.. Also with **msg_type, data_len = struct.unpack('Bi', data)**, I am getting **"struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8"** error.

Comment: I neglected to consider padding - by default, struct will add 3 bytes after the B to align on a 32 bit boundary. You can change this with one of the modifiers `=` (native byte order), `<` (little-endian), `>` (big endian), `!` (network order). Since your format string `"i"` is native order, you can use `"=Bi"`. Since this is a network protocol, it would make sense to use `!` instead, but only if the code generating traffic on the send side does the same thing.

Comment: Adding `"=Bi"` worked!
Just one last nail in thecoffin left now. Suppose, there are multiple files sent from sender side with different **msg_type**. So for file A, I have msg_type=1 and for file B, I have msg_type=2. Now I want to check which msg_type has come and do my thing with it and then use rest part of data send by TCP to detect other msg_type and the data along with it.

As I don't have control over how much data one burst will send, code should be able to handle that part as well.

Comment: You are part way there. When the current code finishes with the file copy it goes to the top of the `while` and waits for the next header. You can add `elif` clauses for the remaining message types. My code assumed that all headers are exactly 5 bytes (msg type and data count). If you have different sized headers depending on type, you should read just 1 byte msg type first.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out @tdelaney. It all worked fine. Found an error at sender end as well. Sender stream was eating up one bit and corrupting complete message.

Comment: Everything worked after changing few things here and there. Just last thing I am stuck in is to break the **while True** loop once I am done receiving the messages/files that I wanted.

This is needed as I need to do some operations on these files that I have received and since recv stays in blocking mode, this causes problem so figuring out simplest way to implement this without having to add additional code for non-blocking.. Just like exiting the while loop when I have the files

Comment: You want to process multiple messages and then exit the loop? That will happen if the other side closes the connection. An option is to create a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to run other threads in the background and queue the work to be done there. its a bit of work and more than will fit in a comment, though.

Comment: I actually managed to do it using simple return False as I knew and can control which message comes the last. Once I receive the last message completely, I am returning False to break the loop. though I would like to implement multi-threading as it seem inevitable as my program starts doing more things.. But we are good for now. Thanks for all your help mate..